# Relative coordinates of an ImageView in Android

Tags: java, android, imageview, coordinates, android-relativelayout

I have a square image in an ImageView contained within a FrameLayout that is right aligned (landscape layout). The FrameLayout is set to FillParent width and height and the ImageView is set to Adjust View Bounds so that the resulting ImageView is a perfect square with each side being the length of the height of the landscape layout, right aligned. However, the original image is larger than this.
I need to get the coordinates clicked on the ImageView in relation to itself (ie. the top left hand corner of the ImageView is 0,0 and the bottom right corner would be the displayed width and height coordinates) so that I can work out if the clicked point was past the mid-point of the ImageView. 
I initially get the size of the ImageView using:

```
int myImageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
int myImageViewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
```

I've created an OnTouchListener and within this I'm using event.getX() and event.getY(), but this seems to return the coordinates relative to the image's oiginal size, not the displayed size. I've also tried the following:

```
Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
float[] values = new float[9];
m.getValues(values);
float relativeX = (event.getX() - values[2]) / values[0];
float relativeY = (event.getY() - values[5]) / values[4];
```

But again this seems to return inaccurate coordinates. Can anyone please help?